# Unable to install Internet Explorer 11

Tags: ie

When I am try to install Internet Explorer using the command `sudo apt-get install wine cabextract`) my VLC player gets unpacked/uninstalled/removed.

Please provide me with a suitable command to install Internet Explorer.

Comment: could I just ask why would you want to run IE11 on a Linux Machine?

Comment: Or on a Windows Machine for that matter!

Comment: @RiaanV I for now do need to run *IE 11* in Ubuntu 16.04 for compatibility test. So I suppose this is the try instead of directly trying to set up a VM in ubuntu. Using Wine and PlayOnLinux can be helpful but there is no *IE 11* as far as I know.

Comment: I don't think the VLC problem is related to installing wine and cabextract. Seems more likely your VLC package is misconfigured or marked for removal, or your packaging system is broken. In order to tell, please post the full output of that `apt-get` command.

Answer (score 2):

The host of that file at http://www.tatanka.com.br now advises

"The new Internet Explorer and Edge can not be run on Wine anymore"

Instead, they recommend

"So Microsoft has its own VMs for this:"

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

"Virtual Box, vagrant, VMWare and others are supported."

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu's default web browser is Mozilla Firefox. Some web sites require Internet Explorer for full functionality, and it is possible to make the browser claim to be Internet Explorer.

To install Internet Explorer you will need to install two components first, Wine and cab extract.

```
sudo apt-get install wine cabextract
```

To finish the install you need to download Internet Explorer.

```
wget http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
cd ies4linux-*
./ies4linux
```

This should open up a GUI. In the case of Command Line being used:

```
Welcome, ! I'm IEs4Linux.
I can install IE 6, 5.5 and 5.0 for you easily and quickly.
You are just four 'enter's away from your IEs.

I'll ask you some questions now. Just answer y or n (default answer is the bold one)

IE 6 will be installed automatically.
Do you want to install IE 5.5 SP2 too? [ y / n ]
```

Select y to install.

```
And do you want to install IE 5.01 SP2? [ y / n ]

IEs can be installed using one of the following locales:
EN-US PT-BR DE FR ES IT NL SV JA KO NO
DA CN TW FI PL HU AR HE CS PT RU EL TR
Default is EN-US. Hit enter to keep it or choose a different one:
```

Hit enter to select the default language or choose another.

```
By default, I will install everything at /home/.../.ies4linux
I will also install Flash 9 plugin and create Desktop shortcuts.
Is that ok for you? (To configure advanced options type n) [ y / n ]
```

Internet Explorer will now install!

Comment: wine is not installing IE 11 as there ins't one yet. The OP  specifically asked for IE11.

Comment: OP specifically said they're having problems with the first step, `sudo apt-get install wine cabextract`. Also this seems to be copied straight from [the Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingInternetExplorer). Please don't plagiarize, instead cite your sources and put quoted material in a quote block.