# I am trying to install internet explorer on my ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, software-installation, wine, ie

So I am trying to install Internet Explorer on my ubuntu 18. I followed these steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944899/unable-to-install-internet-explorer-11#)

```
sudo apt-get install wine cabextract
wget http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
```

As I got the ies4linux-latest.tar.gz file and tried to gunzip and untar it, I am getting the below error :

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

Which means that the file is not properly gzipped and its an HTML or binary or some code. In my case it's an HTML code. So I opened it and had a 1800 line of code.

I tried other links to find the source file but I can't.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  There is no release Ubuntu 18, and by the `apt-get` you listed it looks like you mean a *yy.mm* desktop or server which uses deb packages and *yy.mm* format such as 18.04, and not snap only as in *yy* specialist release (like Ubuntu Core 18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host of that file at http://www.tatanka.com.br  now advises

"The new Internet Explorer and Edge can not be run on Wine anymore"

Instead, they recommend

"So Microsoft has its own VMs for this:"

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

"Virtual Box, vagrant, VMWare and others are supported."